# meaning of: ういっく

Tags: meaning, manga, onomatopoeia

I'm reading a manga and ういっく has come up three different times. Unfortunately, it's the only word/phrase so I can't garner what it means based on context. I've attached the three panels in which I've found this word. Someone, please tell me what it means as I know I'm missing a subtle nuance to the wordplay going on in the manga.

[image: First time ういっくappears]

[image: Second time ういっくappears]

[image: Third time ういっくappears]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> うぃっく

It's an imitative sound of a hiccup often used to describe drunk people.

Comment: For real?! It's the sound of a hiccup? lol. And here I thought it was a real word since the last panel has it in an actual speech bubble.

Comment: 「ウィック」や「うぃっく」で検索してもヒットしませんが、「ウィーック」だとヒットするようです・・・または「ウィック」+「酔っ払い」で

Comment: The typical sound of a hiccup is ヒック and a typical groaning of a drunken person is ウィー.  ウィック is a rather atypical (but understandable) mixture of the two.